# Swing combo box validation error

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jcombobox, event-dispatch-thread

I have a simple program , that asks for an ip address to connect to , a user id and a password. The IP address is selected through / entered into a combobox.

When the user has entered the address and moved onto another field for entering data , a validation routine is called and in case of an invalid address entered , the combobox background changes to red and a label containing an error message is shown.

The problem is that when the user returns back to the ip combo box , the background color remains red.

it does not change.

How do i code the combobox to overcome my problem ?

Comment: Do you use ListCellRenderer?

Comment: @alex2410 No. I'm not aware of ListCellRenderer. So , did not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) on your **JComboBox**. With it you can manage background color when you enter to combobox and exit from it. Heres simple example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
public class Example extends JFrame {

private JComboBox<String> box;

public Example() {
    init();
}

private void init() {
    box = new JComboBox<String>(getObjects());
    box.setBackground(Color.RED);
    box.addFocusListener(getFocusListener());
    JTextField f = new JTextField();
    add(box,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(f,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

private FocusListener getFocusListener() {
    return new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            super.focusGained(arg0);
            box.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            //validate();
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            super.focusLost(arg0);
            box.setBackground(Color.red);
            //validate();
        }
    };

}

private String[] getObjects() {
    return new String[]{"1","22","33"};
}

public static void main(String... s) {
    Example p = new Example();
}

}
```